# How to find the negative inverse of a number?

Tags: javascript, math, language-agnostic, logic

I have two points A and B and a population of points, and I would like to find the distance from each and every point to the line AB.

I first get the slope of the line, and then its Y intercept. And following [Distance between point & line](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iATjsfAX8yc), at second [00:48](https://youtu.be/iATjsfAX8yc?t=47s) it states that we need the negative inverse of the slope (number).

I would like a function that takes any number, and returns the negative inverse of it. Something like `let inverseOfSlope = getInverse(slope);` Please and thanks

```
getDistance(PointA: Object, PointB: Object, Target: Object)
{
    // find slope of the line
    let slope = (PointA.y - PointB.y) / (PointA.x - PointB.x)

    // find y intercept
    let yIntercept = PointA.y + ((-1 * slope) * PointA.x)

    // find inverse negative of the slope
    let newSlope = -1 * getInverse(slope);

    // find new y-intercept
    let NewYintercept = PointA.y + ((-1 * newSlope) * PointA.x)

    // get point of intersection between the two lines
    // by solving the two equations equal to each other

    // calculate distance between target and point of intersection
    // easy

    // return result
}
```

Comment: The negative inverse of a number would just be `-1 / slope`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 4castle comments "the negative inverse of a number" is a trivial thing with no apparent relevance to your problem. Wikipedia gives [the formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points) you need to compute the distance from a point (x0, y0) to a line defined by two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), and that formula is straightforwardly implemented in any language without any need for your getInverse(slope) function.